# accessing folder on remote computer on the same subnet from Java on Ubuntu

Tags: java, io, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to access a folder on other machine of the same network(subnet) from inside my java code in Eclipse on Ubuntu and I'm using the following code: (here Exported_Files is the folder I'm trying to access)

```
File folder= new File ("//192.168.0.100/home/Acc_name/Exported_Files");
System.out.println(folder.toString());
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
System.out.println(listOfFiles[0].getName());**
```

This code returns a null pointer exception even after trying everything such as sharing that folder on the remote pc and replacing the path with "//192.168.0.100/export" where export is the name of the shared name.

Answer (score 0):

you can mount the remote file system with nfs then you can read remote file as local file

```
mount -t nfs  server_IP_addr:/share_name /local_mount_point
```